# Docker-in-Docker issues with connecting to internal container network (Anchore Engine)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having issues when trying to connect to a docker-compose network from inside of a container. These are the files I am working with. The whole thing runs when I  `./run.sh`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker/compose:latest

WORKDIR .
# EXPOSE 8228

RUN apk update
RUN apk add py-pip
RUN apk add jq
RUN pip install anchorecli
COPY dockertest.sh ./dockertest.sh
COPY docker-compose.yaml docker-compose.yaml
CMD ["./dockertest.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  # The primary API endpoint service
  engine-api:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.6.0
    depends_on:
    - anchore-db
    - engine-catalog
    #volumes:
    #- ./config-engine.yaml:/config/config.yaml:z
    ports:
    - "8228:8228"
..................
## A NUMBER OF OTHER CONTAINERS THAT ANCHORE-ENGINE USES ##
..................
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: anchore-net
```

dockertest.sh

```
echo "------------- INSTALL ANCHORE CLI ---------------------"
engineid=`docker ps | grep engine-api | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
engine_ip=`docker inspect $engineid | jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks."cws-anchore-net".IPAddress'`
export ANCHORE_CLI_URL=http://$engine_ip:8228/v1
export ANCHORE_CLI_USER='user'
export ANCHORE_CLI_PASS='pass'
echo "System status"
anchore-cli --debug system status #This line throws error (see below)
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build . -t anchore-runner
docker network create anchore-net
docker-compose up -d
docker run --network="anchore-net" -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock anchore-runner
#docker network rm anchore-net
```

Error Message:

> System status
>
> INFO:anchorecli.clients.apiexternal:As Account = None
>
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 172.19.0.6:8228
>
> Error: could not access anchore service (user=user url=http://172.19.0.6:8228/v1): HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.19.0.6', port=8228): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1 
>   (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Steps:

1. run.sh builds container image and creates network `anchore-net`
2. the container has an entrypoint script, which does multiple things
3. firstly, it brings up the docker-compose network as detached FROM inside the container
4. secondly, nstalls anchore-cli so I can run commands against container network
5. lastly, attempts to get a system status of the anchore-engine (d.c network) but thats where I am running into HTTP request connection issues.

I am dynamically getting the IP of the api endpoint container of anchore-engine and setting the URL of the request to do that. I have also tried passing those variables from command line such as:
`anchore-cli --u user --p pass --url http://$engine_ip/8228/v1 system status` but that throws the same error.

For those of you who took the time to read through this, I highly appreciate any input you can give me as to where the issue may be lying. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should pretty much never use `docker inspect` to look up a Docker-internal IP address; that address only works on one very specific host OS setup.  Use your normal host's IP address or DNS name and the published `ports:` instead.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, do you think you can explain to me a bit more in detail what you mean? I have tried to use localhost, and mapped the ports accordingly but the container from which I am executing these commands doesn't recognize them. I am not super familiar with how network interaction between containers from inside of one works.